# GetByName throws exception if term does not exists

Tags: sharepoint-online, term-store

I am working on PowerShell to create term in SharePoint Online and before I create one I am trying to see if it already exists. In order to see that I am using below "GetByName" function.

```
$objSearchTerm = $objTermSetName.Terms.GetByName($termName)
$clientContext.Load($objSearchTerm)
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

This works if there is a term with the name but throws an exception if the term does not exist.

> Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Specified
>   argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index"

I can not use PnP because I am creating child term with custom properties so please do not suggest PnP solution because PnP doesn't support that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Try..Catch block to catch the exception if it does not exist.  I guess you are trying to catch the error so that it does not stop the execution when there is no term.